# refreshing code without restarting server - rails on osx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, restart

I am running some rails app on an as x device, the app is running on my local in production mode because the app was designed for a linux system. The problem is that I have to restart my server each time I want to refresh my view. How can I go through this issue ? I googled it and I found this trick to run `touch tmp/restart.txt` but it didn't change anything for me

Comment: Are you using Passenger as your production server? Passenger uses `touch tmp/restart.txt` to refresh the code. If not, you'll have to use some other mechanism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you MUST run your app in the production environment, then you can also edit the **config/environments/production.rb** file and set:

```
# In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
# every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
# since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
config.cache_classes = false
```

Answer (score 1):

When starting your rails server you can specify your environment:

Try running:

```
rails server -e development
```